# Rendering redux props map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm trying to render out a redux state by mapping through an array of objects but I'm getting map is not a function. I can console.log my props to see it is receiving but it looks as though it's trying to map through it before the props have been passed into the component. As you can see I've tried also using the && method as others have suggested but all I get back is:

```
TypeError: myItems.map is not a function
```

Here's the code I have

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class RandomComponent extends Component {
    state = {
        myItems: this.props.myItems
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot) {
        console.log('Styles: ', this.props.myItems); // Returns object array 
    }

    render() {
        const {myItems} = this.props; // also tried this.state
        return (
            <ul>
               {myItems && myItems.map((item) => {
                    return <span>Hello.</span>
                })}
            </ul>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    myItems: state.getmyItems.myItems
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RandomComponent);
```

Comment: Can you post how your reducer and action creator looks like?

Comment: Put the console.log into the render() method. myItems does have some value, but it's not an array.

Comment: First, don't bind props to state. Second, you don't have myItems in your reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialState is an object, set it to an empty array []. In your catch return an empty array and not an empty object. The && does not work because an empty object "exists". If u still want to use the && then set initialState to undefined

Answer (score 0):

`map` is a function for **arrays** your data type might be an **object**. To *iterate over* an **object** you can use `for ... in`

Comment: If you can also include the output of your console.log the data type for your `myItems` can be confirmed.